# How to add a year view to a fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am trying to add a year view to a fullcalendar which is not working out.
I can add the daygrid, timegrid and list plugins as provided by fullcalendar as follows:

```
import { Calendar ,EventInput} from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import rrulePlugin from '@fullcalendar/rrule';
import { bindable, inject, Aurelia } from 'aurelia-framework';
@inject(Element)
export class MCalendar extends Component {
    @bindable() initialView: string;    
    @bindable() events: Array<any> = [];
    
    calendarElement: HTMLDivElement;
    private calendar: Calendar;
    constructor(private element: any, aurelia: Aurelia) {
                super(aurelia);
            };
    attached() {
        this.calendar = new Calendar(this.calendarElement, {
            headerToolbar: { left: 'title prev,next today', right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listYear,year' },
            plugins: [integrationPlugin, dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin, rrulePlugin],
            initialView: this.initialView,
            
        });
    }
    }
```

I found the following which is exactly what I want on the year view, but I don't know how to populate it with my above code

[year view](https://codepen.io/rofl86/pen/eoEYMQ)

How do I add the year view?

Comment: That's an old plugin which appears to have been written for fullCalendar 3, or even earlier. It relies on jQuery (as did fullCalendar 3 and below) so it's not easily translateable into the newer versions unfortunately. And lots has changed with the internals of fullCalendar since then as well anyway. In the newer versions you'd need to start by creating a custom view - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js . It's likely to be time-consuming and not for the faint-hearted. Plus you then have to keep it up to date as new versions of fullCalendar come out or else you get left behind

Comment: @ADyson i see on the fullcalendar custom view they have this year option https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-custom-view-demo but im not entirely sure how they got that in there

Comment: That's specific to the timeline view though, because it can scroll sideways infinitely. Totally different if you want the grid layout (like multiple "month" views) as per the demo you showed originally in the question. P.S. if you're unsure how it was achieved in that demo then click the "Edit in CodePen" link in the top-right corner and you can see the code to learn how it was configured. And see also https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-settings for the general approach. But that concept doesn't work with the "month" view unfortunately - it's a fixed grid.